# Compiler error: incompatible types when assigning to 'struct' from type 'void *' during malloc

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

**EDIT** -- can the down voter explain? I have a clear question, with supporting evidence, and proof of prior investigation. I would like to understand why you are down voting me...?

---

I am getting this error when I compile with gcc:

`error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct cell’ from type ‘void *`

The problem lines are:

```
    struct cell* cells = NULL;
    cells = malloc(sizeof(struct cell) * length);
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            cells[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct cell) * width);
```

I believe I have followed the proper protocol, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811439/malloc-an-array-of-struct-pointers) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663031/error-incompatible-types-when-assigning-to-type-values-from-type-void). What am I missing?

Comment: Are you, by any chance, compiling this as _C++_?

Comment: Are you compiling as C++?

Comment: Not unless `~$ gcc program.c` is `g++` in Ubuntu...

Comment: C++ dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099669/invalid-conversion-from-void-to-char-when-using-malloc

C dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Don't you need double pointer for this?

Comment: @AlokSave Yes there is, he is trying to assign the output of `malloc` to a structure value inside of the loop. Also, C++ is a strict superset of C.

Comment: C++ is **not** a *strict* superset of C.

Comment: @HevyLight: I certainly missed seeing the loop. But, **C++ is not a strict superset of C**, both are different languages governed by different language standards. Please stop spreading that lie. To be honest that is pure nonesense.

Comment: @AlokSave You are correct, they are not quite strict supersets. However, if you give `g++` (and any other compiler I can think of) a `.c` file, it will compile it as C regardless. Pure nonsense is also a bit far, as they are rather close.

Comment: @HevyLight: The g++ command is part of gcc, and it determines what language to compile from the extension on the source file name; that has nothing to do with the relationship between the C and C++ languages. `g++ -c foo.adb` will compile `foo.adb` as Ada (if Gnat is installed). And C++, unlike C, doesn't let you assign the `void*` result of `malloc()` to an object of a different pointer type without a cast. C++ fails to be a struct superset of C in a way that is directly relevant to the code in this question. The first `malloc` line is valid C and illegal C++.

Comment: @HevyLight: A c program need not always compile as c++. As a proof pick up the second line in OPs code, one which contains malloc and try to get it compiled as a c++ program, it won't.So yes nonesense is the correct word to describe that statement of yours.

Comment: @HevyLight: For C++ to be a proper superset of C, every legal C program must also be a legal C++ program with identical semantics.  This is not the case.  There are a number of non-trivial incompatibilities between the two.  The differences can be subtle (treatment of void pointers, `const`-qualified objects, meaning of empty parameter lists in function declarations, etc.) to obvious (C++ doesn't support VLAs, can't use C++ keywords as identifiers, etc.)  Better to say the two languages share a large common subset of syntax and semantics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a multidimensional array, you want an array of type `struct cell** cells`:

```
struct cell** cells = NULL;
cells = malloc(sizeof(struct cell*) * length);
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  cells[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct cell)*width);
}
```

Now `cells` is a multidimensional array, where the first index range is the length and the second index range is the width.

Comment: Great, the compiler is happy :) Makes sense, thanks for explaining.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a multidimensional array is simply an array of arrays. You can create a data structure that acts like a multidimensional array (with more flexibility and more need to manage your own memory) using an array of pointers.

Comment: @KeithThompson Is the alternate data structure you are referring to an array that would result from a command something like: `struct cell* cells = malloc(sizeof(struct cell) * length * width);` ?

Comment: @d0rmLife What my code above gives you is an array of pointers to arrays. `struct cell* cells = malloc(sizeof(struct cell) * length * width)` gives you a one dimensional array, but it can be indexed using something along the lines of `cells[i*width+j]`.

Comment: @d0rmLife: Partly. To emulate a 2D array like that, you need to allocate memory both for an array of pointers (each element of which points to a row of the 2D array), and for each row. Basically what you're doing in the code in your question, apart from the type error.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` always returns a pointer of type `void *` you need to type cast

To allocate memory for single element:

`struct cell* new = (struct cell*) malloc(sizeof(struct cell)); //This will allocate memory and new is pointer`

To access data members :

`new->member_name = value; //dot(.) operator doesn't work as new is a pointer and not an identifier`

To allocate memory for array :

`struct cell* base = (struct cell*) malloc(sizeof(struct cell) * length); //This will allocate memory and base is base of array`

To access data members :

`base[i].member_name = value; //When accessing elements of array the -> operator doesn't work.`